# How to make p text which have photo background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm planning to make some control console on the web, but I have some problem while I'm designing project.

At 'apple.com(especially "https://www.apple.com/iphone-xs/")', there are plenty of texts which have images instead of background color. I already analyzed this webpage, but I can't find how to assign this design.

I want to know how to assign designs like this.

[image: https://www.apple.com/iphone-xs/]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip (text value)

Comment: Quite a simple Google search, hopefully this will help you out https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: The technique is referred to as 'knockout text', give'r a google.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this one

```css
.text-block {
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: text;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-block">What a beautiful sunrise</p>
```

Comment: If you only read the question's title this is what you might come up with, but what the OP seems to be after is in fact the opposite effect.

Comment: you are right I misunderstood the question. now I have update my code though lots of neg vote is there lol.

Comment: OK but now your answer is just the same as the other one that was posted before yours. And you didn't explain your answer either.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to use the background clip property.

'background-clip' is a management on how the background should be clipped. Within that you can use 'text' to tell it to clip the background provided inside the text itself.

```css
.txt{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-image: url(http://ajsai.jp/wp-content/themes/ajsai-theme/images/non-thumbnail.jpg);
  }
```

```html
  <p class="txt">BACKGROUND!</p>
```